# How to redefine \section without error in \tableofcontents

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, errors, luatex, compiling

I noticed,what when i redefine section and use \tableofcontents, I get an error:

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

Help me please fix this problem. Thanks everybody very much for any help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tagpdf}
\tagpdfsetup{tabsorder=structure,uncompress,activate-all,add-new-tag=Title/P,interwordspace=true}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\prop_gset_from_keyval:Nn{\g__sections_prop}{chapter=H1,section=H2,subsection=H3,subsubsection=H4}
\prop_map_inline:Nn \g__sections_prop{
\cs_set_eq:cc{orig@#1}{#1}
\cs_gset_protected:cpn{#1}##1{
\tagstructbegin{tag=#2}
\tagmcbegin{tag=#2}
\use:c{orig@#1}{##1x}
\tagmcend
\tagstructend
}
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
\author{Alexandr Kozlovskiy}
\title{test}
\begin{document}
\tagstructbegin{tag=Document}
\tagstructbegin{tag=Title}
\tagmcbegin{tag=Title}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\tagmcend
\tagstructend
\section{test}
\tagstructbegin{tag=P}
\tagmcbegin{tag=P}
new test
\tagmcend
\tagstructend

\section{new test}

\tagstructbegin{tag=P}
\tagmcbegin{tag=P}
new test again
\tagmcend
\tagstructend
\tagstructend
\end{document}
```

Comment: @david-carlisle Ok,but i not understand,how to solve this issue. I tryed to use 
\str_if_eq:nnTF{##1}{*}{\use:c{orig@#1}{##1}{##2}}{\use:c{orig@#1}{##1}},but error not disappear. Pleas,help me solve this problem,to i can understand for future,how to solve the similar problems. ☹

Comment: @david-carlisle please,help me solve this problem. It's very important for me. Or it very difficult to solve my problem. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @david-carlisle About tables,it solves using \atbeginenvironment ant \atendenvironment hooks. \Section it not environment,so it not easy to fix it. Yes,i can use \pre_to_cmd and \app_to_cmd commands of ettolbox package,but i want to know,how redefine this in expl3.I tryed google things like "defining/redefining optional commands with expl3",but i didn't found any solution. Therefore i understood,what i should redefine command with one optional argument and one mandatory,but i redefined it only as command with one argument,so standard variant of this command was deleted.

Comment: @david carlisle But i dont know,how to fix it,using expl3so i ask you to help me,that i can understand,how have to deal with similar cases. So i understood where is a problem,but i dont understood how to fix it. Yes,i can create protected command with one argument and with two arguments,but i not shure,what it will help,and what it's good idea. Thank you very much for your help. About tagging,thank you for link,i will read this. I hope in future in latex 3 in tagged pdf will b features of pdf 2.0 such as associated files,etc. Also i hope,what i can also set alttext and actualtext for tag pdf.

Comment: @david-carlisle I looked the conference of tex 2020,and it's very interesting. As for tagging we develop now axessibility package,which try to do automatic tagging of document. But now i have a issue with sections,which i can not solve. Thank you for link on materials of tex conference 2020.

Comment: As i understand,there is impossible do with expl3.

Comment: @david-carlisle ok,how i can solve this problem for section,if my aproach,which i apply,is incorrect.

Comment: As for basic syntaks,i know,that in latex command with optional arguments i can define as,for example,\newcommand{\c1}[2][def_value_of_first_arg]{my_code}. And what about expl3?

Comment: @david carlisle why your comments became deleted,or it's some tex.stackexchange.com issue?

Comment: The site doesn't support extended discussion in comments, I deleted them

Comment: @david carlisle Ok,how we can continue our discussion,because i understood a problem,but not understood,how to solve it. Thank you very much for your help.